# ListBox Loading Animation

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

I have a list box that should be filed when user click on `Button`,
sometimes the data loaded is quickly, and sometimes it take some time... Is there a simple way to load some animation like a clock, or something which can give the user indication that the process is running?

I use mvvm with button commands

```
  <ListBox Width="30" 
          Visibility="{Binding IsDataLoaded,
          Converter= {StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}"
          FontSize ="15"
          ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" >

                <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DarkGray" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            </ListBox>



             <Button Content="Go"  Command="{Binding GoCommand}" IsEnabled="{Binding IsGoEnabled}" IsDefault="True" Width="60"
                        />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for a [BusyIndicator](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=BusyIndicator) like in the Extended Toolkit.

Comment: Yep,I look for something similar ,this is third party tool?

Comment: It's the extended WPF toolkit, heavily used and relied on by many. You're bound to find other handy things in it if you're not already familiar with it. Definitely worth looking into to make life easier and projects more robust in a lot of cases.

Comment: Thanks Chris,voted up, can you please provide example how I bound it to the list box ?since Im not sure how to use it Thanks in advance

Comment: The documentation is pretty straight forward and there's [loads of tutorials](http://elegantcode.com/2011/10/07/extended-wpf-toolkitusing-the-busyindicator/) for usage of it out on the net. Just wrap your content in it (after you've got the references/assemblies added to your proj of course) and throw `*.IsBusy=True` when you start your task, and `*.IsBusy=False` when it's done.

Comment: I try to use it but Im getting error with the tag for <xctk:BusyIndicator IsBusy="True" BusyContent="Downloading email..." >
            <ContentControl Style="{StaticResource SampleContent}"/>
</xctk:BusyIndicator> despite i put the namespace,any idea?

Comment: Well..what's the error? You added the assemblies etc and followed the documentation and/or tutorials out there for it?